# ESP8266 unresolved mDNS host in .local domain

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to implement a mDNS for esp8266 in Arduino IDE following this guide.

https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap08%20-%20mDNS.html

I cannot get the esp8266.local name to work - when i ping it it returns an error unresolved host and putting it in a browser also does not resolve...

The IP address does resolve though. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am using Mac OS High Sierra and have seen that many people have experienced this problem on both windows and mac but there does not seem to be a solution yet.

Any ideas?

Thanks x

Comment: Post your serial output. Make sure the device is getting an ip address on the network.

Comment: I have had the same issue. It gets an IP address, but seemingly won't use mDNS. I think it's either an OS or router issue. Are you able to try different routers?

Answer (score 2):

There is a known bug in the example code you are using.  The author has been notified on github but has apparently chosen to not update their published code.

You need to add the following line to the loop() { } ; section of the code :    **MDNS.update();**

```
 void loop() {
    MDNS.update();
 }
```

Once you do that. it should start working. And without that there is not way to get it working.

Adding this comment for anyone following and searching for a solution to this same problem.